# Is it possible to directly access files out of a symlink-directory?

Tags: directory, symlink, cd-command

Say I have this directory structure:

```
foo
 │ ╲
bar baz
 │    ╲
wun ← wunl
 │
blarg
```

Here, `wunl` is a symlink pointing to `../bar/wun`. Now I can

```
$ cd foo/baz/wunl/blarg
```

At this point, I'm not “actually” in `wunl`, which is after all not a directory but a symlink, yet `pwd` suggests just that:

```
$ pwd
/home/.../foo/baz/wunl/blarg
```

I can also `cd` out again with relative paths, as if `baz/wunl` had been a normal directory:

```
$ cd ../../
$ pwd
/home/.../foo/baz/
```

However I cannot use such relative paths to, say, copy a file:

```
$ pwd
/home/.../foo/baz/
$ touch test.txt
$ cd wunl/blarg
$ cp ../../test.txt .
cp: cannot stat '/home/.../foo/bar/test.txt': No such file or directory
```

So `cp` tries to use the “realpath expansion” and tries to `..` from there, instead of from the “pseudopath” that `pwd` and `cd` work with.

I *can* still get the desired copy with this hack:

```
$ ( cd ../../ ; cp test.txt wunl/blarg )
```

but this is fiddly and doesn't support tab-completion. Is there a better way?

Comment: `cp` (and also `ls`)  has the "correct" behavior. `..` is a link to the real parent directory. You can use `cd -P ..` to get the same behavior, but I don't think you can change the behavior of `cp` or `ls`.

Comment: See also: https://superuser.com/questions/1217237/why-does-ls-show-real-parent-content-when-im-inside-a-symbolic-link-direct and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642965/with-symbolic-links-why-are-the-results-from-ls-and-cd-different

Comment: @pLumo I don't think my question is a duplicate of any of those questions. They discuss why / how the default behaviour is different between `cd` and other commands, but not how to _make those commands behave_ like `cd` does. (Which clearly has to be _possible_, or at least it is evidently possible to write a bash-wrapper around them that emulates this behaviour.)

Comment: The last link the last sentences of the answer is exactly what you need.

Comment: "Which clearly has to be possible, or at least it is evidently possible to write a bash-wrapper around them that emulates this behaviour"... Possible but troublesome, because cd is a shell built-in, the others aren't. The shell maintains the state that enables this behaviour, it's not easy to get it outside

Comment: @AdminBee yeah, that question _is_ a duplicate, though I'm not really satisfied with the answer given there.